# Handling change events in a div element

Tags: jquery, html

I have a scrollable div element with a number of checkboxes dynamically generated. I need to fire an event every time a different selection is made. i.e. a different set of checkboxes is selected.
I couldn't find any onchange() handler for the  tag. What event of the div can I use to handle this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `<div />` element *itself* does not have a `change` event; but the `change` event for the inputs **will** bubble up through their ancestors; so you can still listen for the event on the `<div />`

```
$('div').on('change', function (e) {
    // in here, `this` is the div element and e.target is the changed checkbox
});
```

The more jQuery-esque way however, will be to *delegate* the handler to the `<div />` element as follows;

```
$('div').on('change', 'input:checkbox', function (e) {
    // in here, `this` is the checkbox and `e.delegateTarget` is the div.
});
```

For more info, see the jQuery documentation for [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on). More information on event bubbling can be found [here](http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2012/05/what-does-event-bubbling-mean/)<sup>my blog</sup>.

Comment: Missed the dynamic thing in the question. +1.